# Store default value in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am developing my first iPhone application. I need store some values in a place where the values will not get lost if the app is deleted.

I need this to get the number of days the user actually used the app. Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

When you delete an app, all data belonging to the app gets deleted. If you wanted to store this sort of data, you would need to store it on a webserver, and get your iPhone app to "phone home" with usage stats.